# R function geom_freqpoly equivalent in Python to plot frequency polygons

Tags: python, r, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

How to plot the frequency polygons in Python?

For example, I can plot density plot like this:

```
import pandas as pd

x = (1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,
         2.5,2.5,2.5,
         3.5,3.5,3.5,3.5,3.5,3.5,
         4.5,4.5,
         6.5,6.5,6.5,6.5,6.5,6.5,6.5,6.5)

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x})
#df.head()

df.plot(kind='density')
```

This gives:

[image]

However, I want the polygon like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

x = c(1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,
         2.5,2.5,2.5,
         3.5,3.5,3.5,3.5,3.5,3.5,
         4.5,4.5,
         6.5,6.5,6.5,6.5,6.5,6.5,6.5,6.5)

df = data.frame(x=x)
# head(x)

ggplot(data=df, mapping = aes(x=x)) + 
  geom_freqpoly(binwidth=2)
```

[image]

**UPDATE**
I tried the solution by @Quang Hoang for a problem given in the book "R for Data Science" by Hadley and got a similar result.

Book:

[image]
[image]

I have saved the nycflights13 data obtained from R and place it in github.

Here is my attempt to obtain the same plot:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

flights = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/bhishanpdl/Datasets/blob/master/nycflights13.csv?raw=true')

not_cancelled = flights.dropna(subset=['dep_delay','arr_delay'])
not_cancelled.dep_delay.isnull().sum(), not_cancelled.arr_delay.isnull().sum()

delays = not_cancelled.groupby('tailnum')['arr_delay'].mean().reset_index()


x = delays.arr_delay.values
m = int(x.max())
counts, bins = np.histogram(x, bins=range(-80,m,10))
plt.plot(bins[:-1]+1, counts)
```

[image]

Comment: I have problems relating the data to the plot. E.g. you have data between 1.5 and 6.5, yet the plot ranges from 0 to 8. Why would a binwidth of 2 not result in a plot with bin edges of 1,3,5,7 ?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I am not familiar either. These are the default examples I am trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to replicate the R graph with

```
counts, bins = np.histogram(df.x, bins=range(-1,10,2))
plt.plot(bins[:-1]+1, counts)
```

Output:

[image]

But if you are not really sure what you are looking for, it's hard to tell which/how to modify for general situation.

Comment: Thanks for great help. I tried your method for the actual problem of the book "R for Data Science" and I got same answer. Thanks a lot.